# Dark mode specific to Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, html-email, email-client

I'm wondering if I could change the outlook darkmode same as I did with Mac Darkmode
[image: Thats how it's supposed to look]

[image: Thats how it's displayed.]

Other clients are displaying it right. On Mac, Outlook inverts that white bg I added to images, and other clients simply don't display anything.

How can I specify the rules for Outlook Darkmode?

Comment: I don't have time right now to go into full details, but check out https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-dark-mode-for-email-marketers/ and https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-fix-outlook-dark-mode-problems--cms-37718

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.